# Connecting my ubuntu pc to tv and getting netflix to run full screen on the tv?

Tags: 13.10, tv, netflix

When I connect my ubuntu pc to the tv, the screen is fully mirrored on the tv but when I run netflix it only fills up about 1/4th of the screen. Is there a way I can fill up the whole screen while running netflix. For clarification the whole screen is filled when browsing the internet.

Comment: What is the screen resolution and the TV resolution?

Comment: I have a toshiba tv model 32av502rz and a toshiba s855-s5369 laptop. I believe the screen resolution for both is 1368 x 768

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix this by having Netflix closed, switching the main display in "Displays" to the tv, and *then* opening netflix. It should default to the tv as main display and use it's dimensions/resolution.